# iframe cross domain get CSS

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, cross-domain, xss

I have an html page with css, I need the css to control the content of an iframe on that page. I have control of the page in the iframe and the following code works if both the page and frame are local to each other:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    if (parent) {
        var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var arrStyleSheets = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("style");
        for (var i = 0; i < arrStyleSheets.length; i++)
        oHead.appendChild(arrStyleSheets[i].cloneNode(true));
    }
}
</script>
```

However does not work when the page with the iframe and the page the iframe is on are on separate domains. Does any one have any idea how I could get it to work across two domains, or have an alternative solution?

Thanks in advance :)

---

as it is my page that is displayed in iframe could I not just allow users to have their css override mine??

Answer (score 0):

The site you load in the frame must [grant you permission using CORS](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors) before you can instruct your visitors' browsers to exchange information between it and your site with JS. By default [this is forbidden for sensible security reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

Add this HTTP Header on the target site:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

See http://ox86.tumblr.com/post/17652823257/cross-domain-ajax-for-your-api-endpoints

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Cross-document messaging](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging). Basically, the algorithm should work something like this:

- in the parent frame, add a message listener `f` before the iframe is loaded.
- in the iframe, set up a message listener `g` and send a message to `f` after onload
- `f` sends the CSS urls as a JSON-serialized message, and `g` loads the CSS into the iframe